# Plots from excel with panda and seaborn 'ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types'

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, seaborn

I am trying to configure a template for creating plots for my test data. Therefore I need to say I am pretty new to that in python, and I already googled quite a lot regarding my question but what I found could not help me. I have a excel table with data in two columns, which I want to plot against each other. My code looks as follows

```
file='C:/Documents/Test/test_file.xlsx'
df1=pd.read_Excel(file,sheet_name='sheet1',header=0, engine="openpyxl")
plt.figure()
sns.lineplot(data=df1[:,:],x="eps",y="sigma",sort=False,linewidth=0.8)
```

The excel has -as mentioned a header with eps and sigma as x and y values. The values following are floats, when I check the datatype with df1.dtypes, the result is 'float64' So has anyone an idea what is not working? I get the error  'ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types'

Plotting data from excel with panda and seaborn against each other and save the image.

Comment: You might want to add the output of `df1.describe()` to your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a library issue. I've been running into the same problem with example datasets and even a very simple:

```
sns.lineplot(x=[1], y=[1])
```

I'll update if I find a solution.

Edit: There seems to be an issue with Numpy that is causing this issue with Seaborn. Solution is to downgrade Numpy to 1.23 until 1.24.1 is released.

https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/3192

Comment: Yeah. I used an older development environment and I'm not getting this error. Might be a Seaborn bug.

Comment: Here's the issue being tracked: https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/3195

Comment: Ok. Here's the solution: https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/3192. Downgrade to Numpy 1.23. I'll edit answer.